# Cake build DotNet Core error

Tags: .net-core, cakebuild

I'm trying build my solution with dotnet core using cake but I receive it:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets(73,5): error : Project '*xxx.csproj*' targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'. [xxx.csproj]

What could be wrong?

If I run dotnet.exe build on cmd, the builds work normally

- dotnet build *xxx.csproj*

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> CouchDB.Driver.Core -> *xxx.dll*
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.50

### Environment Machine

- The *xxx.csproj* version is:

  > netcoreapp1.1
- cake --version

  > Version 0.19.1+Branch.main.Sha.4c5b4fd5b1c4d9d36066ec78714027e26b211af4
- dotnet.exe --version

  > 1.0.1
- dotnet.exe

  > Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  >
  > Version  : 1.1.0
  >    Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

Comment: If you run with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658660/how-to-enable-diagnostic-verbosity-for-cake what dotnet command is actually being ran?

Comment: How does your Cake script look? Are you using the MSBuild alias or 
DotNetCoreBuild one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot 2 things. The solution is:

1. Set correct framework in **build.cake**:

   ```
    var settings = new DotNetCoreBuildSettings
    {
        Framework = "netcoreapp1.1",
        Configuration = "Release",
        OutputDirectory = "./build/"
    };

    DotNetCoreBuild("./src/", settings);
   ```
2. Restore NuGet packages using the **DotNetCoreRestore** instead nuget.exe

   ```
   Task("Restore-NuGet-Packages")
   .IsDependentOn("Clean")
   .Does(() =>    {
        DotNetCoreRestore("src"); // use it instead of NuGetRestore("./folder");
   });
   ```

The result is:

> Build
>   Executing task: Build
>   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> CouchDB.Driver.Core -> xxx.dll
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:11.10
>   Finished executing task: Build