# Cake Build Script: Error when running XUnit Integration Tests - Cannot get ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FlexConnString"]

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit, cakebuild

I have an integration test using XUnit that accesses the database. We need to be able to get the database connection string from the app.config file.

When running the test from the IDE it works beautifully and the connection string is found.
When I run the test automatically from a cake.build the  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blahblah"]  ret

```
var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FlexConnString"];
if (connectionStringSettings == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConfigManager does not return a setting for FlexConnString");
        _connectionString = "No Connection string";
    }
```

The Cake Task is

```
Task("Run-Integration-Tests")
.IsDependentOn("Run-Unit-Tests")
.Does(() =>
{
    var testDir = "./artifacts/_tests/**/*.IntegrationTests.dll";
    Information("Start Running Integration Tests in " + testDir);
    XUnit2(testDir,
        new XUnit2Settings {
            Parallelism = ParallelismOption.All,
            HtmlReport = true,
            NoAppDomain = true,
            NUnitReport = true,
            XmlReport = true,
            ReportName = "MixTdiIntegrationTestResults",
            OutputDirectory = "./artifacts"
       });
});
```

This outputs ConfigManager does not return a setting for FlexConnString' when running the build.cake from powershell.

I'm not sure if this is an XUnit issue or a Cake issue.

Comment: If you launch cake with diagnostic verbosity you'll get more logging and the command line used to launch xunit. You can read more about in in the below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658660/how-to-enable-diagnostic-verbosity-for-cake

Answer (score 2):

when you are running Xunit test it looks for config file in the current working directory, you can easily check it

```
Information("Current Directory: {0}", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

and can't find it, you need to specify [WorkingDirectory](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/A29EC283) in the [XUnit2Settings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.XUnit/XUnit2Settings/) to folder with  connection string config file

```
XUnit2(testDir,
    new XUnit2Settings {
        Parallelism = ParallelismOption.All,
        HtmlReport = true,
        NoAppDomain = true,
        NUnitReport = true,
        XmlReport = true,
        ReportName = "MixTdiIntegrationTestResults",
        OutputDirectory = "./artifacts",
        WorkingDirectory = "[your config file path]"
   });
```

Need to mention another option is to change your current working directory

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "c:/";
```

Comment: this didnt work. the config file is in the output directory, the `Environment.Currentdirectory` reports the correct folder and the working directory in `XUnit2Settings` is correct

Comment: fix for me was to set ShadowCopy to false (its always bloody shadow copy!) `ShadowCopy = false`