# Use Cake to build .Net Core project using Debug configuration

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I seem to be unable to persuade Cake to build my .Net core project in Debug configuration.

At the moment I have this:

```
void BuildProject(string projectPath, string configuration)
{
    var settings = new DotNetCoreBuildSettings();
    settings.Configuration = "Debug";

    DotNetCoreBuild(projectPath, settings);
}

...

Task("Build")
   .IsDependentOn("RestorePackages")
   .Does(() => 
   {
       BuildProject("src/DlnaCore.Server/DlnaCore.csproj", configuration);
   });
```

which just builds the release config.

Having scoured what I can find in the docs I cannot seem to find the correct incantation :-/

Comment: If you run the build with Diagnostic Verbosity, what `dotnet` command is actually emitted from Cake (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658660/how-to-enable-diagnostic-verbosity-for-cake)

Comment: @GaryEwanPark This confirms that it is actually building in Release: `Executing: "C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" build "src/DlnaCore.Server/DlnaCore.csproj" --configuration Release`

Comment: Can you also confirm what version of Cake you are using?

Comment: Version 0.21.1+Branch.main.Sha.9ff85bb53ea1890fabeb709d38ba79d3bf5cb16f

Comment: Can you try clearing out your local tools folder, and trying again?  This is the only thing I can think of.  I have just tried the above code that you have posted, and the expected command is emitted from Cake, i.e. `Executing: "C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" build "src/DlnaCore.Server/DlnaCore.csproj" --configuration bob` where I obviously changed `Debug` to `bob` within `BuildProject`.

Comment: You should build the solution instead of the project directly.

Comment: @Patrik - not sure that should make any difference? Is there a reason for suggesting that? As it stands I don't even have a solution file.

Comment: Not sure, but information about the configurations are normally stored in the solution file. I've had a lot of problems building projects directly with the new dotnet MSBuild tooling.

Comment: @Patrik I don't think that's the issue for me. I can enter the `dotnet build --configuration "Debug"` command myself and get the results I need.

Comment: @Stewart_R I see. I have no clue then. I use Cake to build projects with Release configuration with the latest tooling and it works for me. Best bet would be to try to reproduce this and post an issue at github.com/cake-build/cake

Comment: Can you post more of your build script, maybe there is an issue there. I'm just guessing because of the unused `configuration` parameter in your current sample. What command line parameters do you use to call cake?

Comment: The reason for suggesting it was to ensure that you actually have the latest Cake in the tools folder. Assuming you are using a packages.config file to restore the Cake version, if you already had a previous version restored to the tools folder, it may not have overridden with the latest version.

Comment: Did you get this work in the end?

Comment: I did. I had made a bit of a catalogue of errors... The above would work were it not for the other mistakes. What's the SO protocol when one makes a pigs ear of the question? Apologise and delete it? Leave it there for others? Either way I really appreciate everyone's kind help & suggestions. Sorry for being a wally :-/