# Build Net Framework web application referencing net-standard library with Cake build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-standard, cakebuild

I have two projects: `NET Standard` class library and regular NET Framework web application. Web application references class library.

I use `Visual Studio 2017 Preview`.

When I try to build the solution with `Cake` using `MSBuild` command I get the unsupported project message:

`error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the
 MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MS
Build 2003 format.`

If I try to use `DotNetCoreBuild` I get:

`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2-vspre-006949\Microsoft\VisualStu
dio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

But the solution is built successfully by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest `MSBuild` version has the targets to build `NET Standard` libraries. The problem is in `Visual Studio Preview` installation path: `Cake` can't find the latest `MSBuild`.

It will also fail if you will try to specify `VS2017` in [MSBuildToolVersion](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildToolVersion/).

You have to specify the `MSBuild` executable manually to make it work with `VS Preview`.

```
string msBuildPath = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe";

MSBuild("../NetStdExample.sln", new MSBuildSettings {
    Verbosity = Verbosity.Minimal,
    ToolPath = msBuildPath
});
```

Update by @Gary Ewan Park: there is a [tool](https://cakebuild.net/blog/2017/03/vswhere-and-visual-studio-2017-support) for determining latest VS install.

Comment: You might want to have a look here: https://cakebuild.net/blog/2017/03/vswhere-and-visual-studio-2017-support rather than hard code the path.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.