# CAKE: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, teamcity, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
var teamCityLoggerZipFolderPath = @".\TeamCity\CustomLogger\VSTest.TeamCityLogger.zip";
var dllDestinationFolder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions";

ZipAliases.Unzip(new FilePath(teamCityLoggerZipFolderPath), 
                 new DirectoryPath(dllDestinationFolder));
```

The idea is to unzip the folder and store its contents in `dllDestinationFolder`.

However, I keep seeing this error message:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'outputPath' of 'ZipAliases.Unzip(ICakeContext, FilePath, DirectoryPath)'
```

As far as I can see, I am calling the `FilePath` and `DirectoryPath` constructors correctly, as documented [here](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/FilePath/) and [here](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/DirectoryPath/). I also don't think I am invoking `ZipAliases.Unzip` [erroneously](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/ZipAliases/C0D68FE5).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip is available through the DSL as either a global method or an extension method to ICakeContext.

So you could just invoke it as `Unzip` or `Context.Unzip`, example:

```
var teamCityLoggerZipFolderPath = @".\TeamCity\CustomLogger\VSTest.TeamCityLogger.zip";
var dllDestinationFolder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions";

Unzip(teamCityLoggerZipFolderPath, dllDestinationFolder);


Context.Unzip(teamCityLoggerZipFolderPath, dllDestinationFolder);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I changed it to ``Context.Unzip``, but now I see the error message ``Error: One or more errors occurred.`` (Very useful, I know.) The same error message was displayed for ``Unzip`` as well.

Comment: Try launching cake with diagnostic verbosity.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658660/how-to-enable-diagnostic-verbosity-for-cake

Comment: I corrected the errors and your suggested changes work fine now.

Comment: Great that it got sorted the "One or more errors occurred" message is a regression and will be sorted in the next release to print the exception message.

Comment: That is great to hear. It is such an utterly useless error message that it makes my blood boil...