# Cake MSBuild Targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, cakebuild, msbuild-target

I am trying to use `Cake`'s built in `MSBuild` functionality to only build a specific Target (i.e. `Compile`). Using the example at: https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildAliases/C240F0FB

```
var settings = new MSBuildSettings()
{
    Verbosity = Verbosity.Diagnostic,
    ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017,
    Configuration = "Release",
    PlatformTarget = PlatformTarget.MSIL
};
settings.WithTarget("Compile");

MSBuild("./src/Cake.sln", settings);
```

But it seems to build all targets, where as i would like to only build a specific target, as detailed in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation here:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettingsExtensions/01F8DC03

The `WithTarget` extension method returns the same instance of the MSBuildSettings with the modifications, it doesn't interact with the current instance.  As a result, where you have:

```
settings.WithTarget("Compile");
```

Is actually not doing anything.  However, if you do this:

```
var settings = new MSBuildSettings()
{
    Verbosity = Verbosity.Diagnostic,
    ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017,
    Configuration = "Release",
    PlatformTarget = PlatformTarget.MSIL
};

MSBuild("./src/Cake.sln", settings.WithTarget("Compile");
```

It should work how you intend it.

To help with this sort of thing, you can run Cake in diagnostic mode, to see exactly what command is being sent to the command line for execution.  You can find more about that in this related question:

[How to enable diagnostic verbosity for Cake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658660/how-to-enable-diagnostic-verbosity-for-cake)

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for answering.
Unfortunately that builds other Targets too. I only want to build a specific Target and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not familar with Cake but if you only want specific targets built why not create a new build configuration and feed the name of that configuration into the `Configuration` variable?

Comment: Have you inspected the command line arguments that are being used when running Cake in diagnostic mode?  How does what Cake emit differ from what you are wanting?