# Change verbosity for cake frosting project

Tags: cakebuild

I'm converting a cake script to a frosting project.

There are [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38658796/9971404) for a script's verbosity. For frosting verbosity what I [found](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/runners/cake-frosting#switches) was the `--verbosity foo` switch.

I tried two things:

1. In the bootstrap script or the shell, I used `--verbosity=foo`
2. I changed the verbosity of the dotnet commands: `context.DotNetClean(path, new DotNetCleanSettings { Verbosity = DotNetVerbosity.Foo });`

So it seems like there are two verbosities - of cake frosting itself, and of the dotnet tool. I can't control that of **frosting** - for example, I can't see what command was issued.

Is that possible with frosting? (If not, I could just log each command manually before calling it, not a big deal.)

Comment: Are you saying that running `dotnet run -- --verbosity=diagnostic` does not change the verbosity on a frosting project?

Comment: @Nils It doesn't change the verbosity for me. I didn't know what to expect. Given the solution below, I now know that the problem is on my side, so I will dig into it to find what I configured incorrectly. Thanks for confirming that for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a Cake Frosting build with `--verbosity=<VERBOSITY>` (e.g. `--verbosity=diagnostic`) Cake Frosting runs with the specified diagnostic.

If you run tools, like `dotnet` from Cake verbosity is not automatically passed to the tool. Most aliases for tools have a property where you can define verbosity of the called tool, like you already mentioned:

```
context.DotNetClean(
  path, 
  new DotNetCleanSettings 
  { 
    Verbosity = DotNetVerbosity.Diagnostic 
  });
```

It is also possible to set the tool verbosity based on the verbosity Cake is currently running. You can retrieve the Cake verbosity from the context:

```
var currentCakeVerbosity = context.Log.Verbosity;
```

Comment: The problem is obviously a configuration issue on my side. But at least the frosting project has a canonical verbosity answer now. Thanks Pascal!

Answer (score 1):

@lonix, there are three places you can check:

1. The bootstrapper: Make sure the bootstrapper "forwards" the arguments you give it to the call to `dotnet`. I.e. the PowerShell bootstrapper should end in `-- $args`
2. The `Main` method should take the arguments from the commandline. I.e. the signature should be `Main(string[] args)`
3. The arguments should be passed to frosting: Make sure that in `.Run(args)` of the `CakeHost`, the `args` are exactly those of the parameters of the `Main` method.

Also, be aware that verbose output in frosting looks a bit different from those of Cake scripting. (I.e. all the startup code of finding and loading modules/addins will not be there.)

Comment: That was it! You helped me track down my config issue. Your and Pascal's answers are very helpful for frosting verbosity, I'm sure it'll help others too. Thank you.